# Arrange by multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr, network-analysis

Having the following dataset:

```
test <- data.frame(name= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), v1 = c(2, 4, 1, 1, 2), v2 = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5))

  name v1 v2
    A  2  3
    B  4  4
    C  1  2
    D  1  1
    E  2  5
```

I want to test a concept of actor/node dominance, which means that for each row/entry I want to see if it has the highest value in the dataset. For example B is higher than A, C and D for both v1 and v2. So it "dominates" all the other rows. E for example is only higher than A, C and D, so it dominates those 3 rows.

Mathematically speaking, what I'm searching for is `i >= j, for v1_i >= v1_j and v2_i >= v2_j.`

Arranging or sorting by columns doesn't work because it doesn't really show how one row will impose another as it sorts first by one column and then by another.

EDIT:Just to add an example an end output would be:

```
B dominates A, C, D
E dominates A, D, C
C dominates D
A dominates C, D
```

Doesn't really matter how it would look like. If it's in the form of a directed network/matrix or a table with a variable with all the letters.

Comment: @RonakShah did that. I hope that it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Why `b` dominates `e` ?

Comment: @AlexandreB. my mistake. Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. It's probably not the most elegant solution.
We can have a function `compare` that checks if one letter dominates the other (unless it is the identical letter), and then use two nested `sapply`s.

```
my_letters <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
test <- data.frame(name= my_letters, v1 = c(2, 4, 1, 1, 2), v2 = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5))

get_row<-function(letter){
  test[test$name==letter,2:ncol(test)]
}

compare<-function(letter,i){
  if(letter!=i){
    if(!sum(get_row(letter) < get_row(i))){
      return(i)     
    }
  }
}

result <- sapply(my_letters, function(let) unlist(sapply(my_letters, compare, letter=let)))
```

results in a list:

```
$A
  C   D 
"C" "D" 

$B
  A   C   D 
"A" "C" "D" 

$C
  D 
"D" 

$D
NULL

$E
  A   C   D 
"A" "C" "D"
```

Answer (score 2):

i got a way out hope this helps :)

```
 c$v3= rowSums(x = c[,-1])
 c = c[order(c$v3,decreasing = T),]
 k = length(c$name)
 for (i in 1:k ) {
   if (i == k) {

   }else {
    a = c$name[i+1:k]
    a = as.character(a[!is.na(a)])
    b = c$name[i]
    b  = as.character(b[!is.na(b)])

   cat(b,"greater than ", a,"\n",sep=" ") 
 }

}
```

so your output will be

```
 B greater than  E A C D 
 E greater than  A C D 
 A greater than  C D 
 C greater than  D
```

Answer (score 2):

`for` loop are very **inefficient** in **R**. Please, avoid them !
You can simply do it with `apply`:

```
# Names column
names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
# Dataframe
test <- data.frame(name= names, v1 = c(2, 4, 1, 1, 2), v2 = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5))

# Display function
findLowerValues <- function(row, test, names) {
  rep <- test$v1 <= row["v1"] & test$v2 <= row["v2"] & test$name != row["name"]
  cat(row["name"], 'dominates', names[rep], "\n")
}

# Apply the display function
# axis : row
# Extra args: the full dataset and names
apply(test, 1, findLowerValues, test=test, names=names)
# A dominates C D 
# B dominates A C D 
# C dominates D 
# D dominates  
# E dominates A C D 
# NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

We first `split` every row into list of rows and pass it to `mapply`, `rep`eat each row `nrow(test)` times, compare them with the entire dataframe `test` and select the `name` which has all values greater than that row. As this will also match rows with itself as well we use `setdiff` to remove those `name` values.

```
mapply(function(x, y) setdiff(
   test$name[rowSums(x[rep(1, nrow(test)),] >= test[-1]) == ncol(test) - 1], y), 
   split(test[-1], test$name), test$name)

#$A
#[1] "C" "D"

#$B
#[1] "A" "C" "D"

#$C
#[1] "D"

#$D
#character(0)

#$E
#[1] "A" "C" "D"
```

**data**

```
test <- data.frame(name= c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), v1 = c(2, 4, 1, 1, 2),
                   v2 = c(3, 4, 2, 1, 5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind a `data.table` solution, a possibility is using non-equi joins as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)
test[test, on=.(v1<=v1, v2<=v2), .(actor=i.name, node=x.name), by=.EACHI, allow.cartesian=TRUE][ 
    actor!=node, .(actor, node)]
```

output:

```
   actor node
1:     A    C
2:     A    D
3:     B    A
4:     B    C
5:     B    D
6:     C    D
7:     E    A
8:     E    C
9:     E    D
```